# Xlookup with panda in Python

Tags: python, junit-jupiter, xlookup

I am very new to Python and i would like to use xlookup in order to look for values in different columns (column"Debt", column "Liquidity" etc..) in a database

And fill the value in the cells (C17, C18, c19....) of a number of destination files which have the same format

```
path_source= r"C:\Test source.xlsx"

destination_file= r"C:Stress Test Q4 2022\test.xlsx"
    
df1 = pd.read_excel(path_source)
df2= pd.read_excel(destination_file)
```

```
def xlookup(lookup_value, lookup_array, return_array, if_not_found:str = ''):
    match_value = return_array.loc[lookup_array == lookup_value]
    if match_value.empty:
        return f'"{lookup_value}" not found!' if if_not_found == '' else if_not_found

    else:
        return match_value.tolist()[0]
```

```
    
df2.iloc[2,17]= df1["debt"].apply(xlookup, args = (main_df1["Fund name"],main_df1["fund_A"] ))
```

> NameError: name 'main_df1' is not defined

can anyone help correct the code ?
thanks a lot

Comment: Your destination file path does not look right:  `destination_file= r"C:Stress Test Q4 2022\test.xlsx"`

Comment: The error is telling you that you have not defined `main_df1`. And from what I can see, the error is correct. Did you mean `df1` instead ?

Comment: yes i mean df1, i changed to df1 and i got error message:
key error: 'fund_A'

Comment: That means you do not have a column named `fund_A`. You can find the names of the columns by using : `print(list(df1.columns))`

Comment: actually fund_A is the key I am using to do the xlookup, the column name is "debt" that is looked for data, or where should I put the key please?